# Iterate through list of tuples with strings and ints

Tags: list, loops, haskell, tuples

So I have this function

```
getSales :: (Num p, Eq t) => t -> [(t, p)] -> p
getSales day [] = 0
getSales day ((x,y):xs) | (day == x) = y + (getSales day xs) | otherwise = getSales day XS
```

So basically if I did getSales "Mon" storelog

and storelog was storelog = [("Mon",50),("Fri",20), ("Tue",20),("Fri",10),("Wed",25),("Fri",30)]

it would return 50. But now I want to be able to iterate through a tuple like this

```
sales = [("Amazon",[("Mon",30),("Wed",100),("Sat",200)]), ("Etsy",[("Mon",50),("Tue",20),("Wed",25),("Fri",30)]), ("Ebay",[("Tue",60),("Wed",100),("Thu",30)]), ("Etsy",[("Tue",100),("Thu",50),("Sat",20),("Tue",10)])]
```

With the company name given and then I use getSales to find the sales for the day asked.

```
sumSales:: (Num p)=> String -> String -> [(String,[(String,p)])] -> p
```

This is the function I have for the iteration for the company name given and such but I am having a real hard time understanding how to iterate through the tuple for it to find "Amazon" for example and then pass in the list of the sales for the days.

Answer (score 0):

You've actually already implemented most of the logic needed in your `getSales` function - which I repeat below for reference, although tidying up the recursive case to put the guards on separate lines, this is much more readable and is how it would normally be written in practice:

```
getSales :: (Num p, Eq t) => t -> [(t, p)] -> p
getSales day [] = 0
getSales day ((x,y):xs)
  | (day == x) = y + (getSales day xs)
  | otherwise = getSales day XS
```

For your `sumSales` function, you just need to repeat this pattern. The only important differences are:

- the function takes 2 arguments instead of 1
- the second element of the tuples, denoted by `y` above, now isn't simply a number, but a list of tuples. So we can't simply add it to the result of the recursive call. However, what it is is a tuple consisting of a day name and a number, which is exactly the case you've already dealt with in `getSales`. So the solution is to make use of that function you've already written.

Taking account of the above, we get:

```
sumSales:: (Num p) => String -> String -> [(String, [(String, p)])] -> p
sumSales company day [] = 0
sumSales company day ((x, y) : xs)
  | company == x = getSales day y + sumSales company day xs
  | otherwise = sumSales company day xs
```

which will work as I believe you intend.

However, I don't particularly like these two functions. They are very "noisy", with a lot of details to process before you can understand what the functions do - and further, the important parts of the two functions are more or less the same. In particular, one common way in functional programming to write functions like these which "summarise" some information about a list is to use a "fold". So you could rewrite the functions in this way, which uses `foldr` to abstract away the common recursion pattern in both:

```
getSales day = foldr (\(x, y) sum -> if x == day then y + sum else sum) 0
sumSales company day = foldr (\(x, sales) sum -> if x == company then getSales day sales + sum else sum) 0
```

That is, in my opinion, better - but still not great. There's still repetition across the functions which we're using to fold in each case - both simply check a condition and use it to either add a new term or not.

The Haskell standard library - in fact, even the Prelude, the set of functions/types/classes available by default in every Haskell program, without any imports - already includes some functions for dealing with these things. In particular, there is [sum](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) for adding a list of numbers, [filter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) for reducing a list to just those elements fulfilling a particular condition, and [map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) for getting a new list from an old one by applying a function to each element. `map`, `filter` and the various folds are really the "bread and butter" of functional programming with lists, so I would advise becoming familiar and comfortable with them.

Using these common tools, we can write the two functions in much more readily understandable form:

```
getSales day = sum . map snd . filter (\(x, _) -> x == day)
sumSales company day = sum . map (getSales day . snd) . filter (\(x, _) -> x == company)
```

(One could argue I've taken these too far in terms of being "point free" - although I could have gone further and written eg `\(x, _) -> x == day` as `(== day) . fst`. The "best" way to write a function, in terms of readability, is very much a matter of opinion. I just wanted to show you that there are other ways to write these functions, and other similar ones you may need in future, that will likely make more sense to you when you come back to look at them later.)